# Repeating non-overlapping substrings

Tags: python, substring

This is finding the longest repeating substring code (source: geeksforgeeks):

```
def longestRepeatedSubstring(str): 

    n = len(str) 
    LCSRe = [[0 for x in range(n + 1)] 
                for y in range(n + 1)] 

    res = "" # To store result 
    res_length = 0 # To store length of result 

    # building table in bottom-up manner 
    index = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1): 
        for j in range(i + 1, n + 1): 

            # (j-i) > LCSRe[i-1][j-1] to remove 
            # overlapping 
            if (str[i - 1] == str[j - 1] and
                LCSRe[i - 1][j - 1] < (j - i)): 
                LCSRe[i][j] = LCSRe[i - 1][j - 1] + 1

                # updating maximum length of the 
                # substring and updating the finishing 
                # index of the suffix 
                if (LCSRe[i][j] > res_length): 
                    res_length = LCSRe[i][j] 
                    index = max(i, index) 

            else: 
                LCSRe[i][j] = 0

    # If we have non-empty result, then insert 
    # all characters from first character to 
    # last character of string 
    if (res_length > 0): 
        for i in range(index - res_length + 1, 
                                    index + 1): 
            res = res + str[i - 1] 

    return res 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    str = "geeksforgeeks"
    print(longestRepeatedSubstring(str)) 

# This code is contributed by ita_c
```

How can it be modified to obtain also the shorter repeating non-overlapping substrings starting with the substrings of length x and ending with the longest substring? (tried various changes but never got the correct result).

Comment: Could you please provide examples of inputs and expected outputs ? It will help users to answer

Comment: `How can it be modified to obtain also the shorter ` The shortest will be always length 1 or 0 (empty string is theoretically a substring). What do you understand by "shorter"? Do you want second longest? Or any string? Or if there are two of the same (longest) length, get them both instead of one longest?

Comment: All repeated substrings with length x and longer (up to the longest) shall be found. The number of repetitions doesn't matter. There must not be any overlapping and no substrings of a longer substring. I.e. none of the substrings in the result table shares any element with any other substring. Example: x=3, string: 47358917948809837074317946984339473589669843698370880, result: 880//1794//69843//98370//473589

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming it's some kind of programming exercise, I don't want to provide the code itself. I'll provide hints.**

---

> How can it be modified to obtain also the shorter repeating non-overlapping substrings starting with the substrings of length x and ending with the longest substring? (tried various changes but never got the correct result).

Please let me know if I understand you correctly...

You want to get all non-overlapping longest substrings, right?

First problem: Non-overlapping means that longest substring can cut the other long substrings. And vice versa. Search from longest to x, instead of from x to longest.

Second problem: what do we care about more - length or number of strings?

---

If we care only about the longest at the current moment, you can:

1. find the longest match
2. if its length is longer than wanted `x`, save it (otherwise quit)
3. remove all (? what if the string has e.g. 3 repetitions of the longest, instead of 2?) occurrences of the longest string from the string; keep some delimeter in its place (because e.g. `abbcacbb` has the longest substring `bb` - just removing it will yield `acac`, giving `ac`, which is wrong)
4. repeat

That's basically pseudocode that you need to "translate" into real code. Use `while` loop. ;)

You don't need to modify the given function - as you can see, point 1 is using it as it is. You just need to get results from multiple calls to that function. ;)

Comment: All repeated substrings with length x and longer (up to the longest) shall be found. The number of repetitions doesn't matter. There must not be any overlapping and no substrings of a longer substring. I.e. none of the substrings in the result table shares any element with any other substring. Example: string: 47358917948809837074317946984339473589669843698370880, result: 880//1794//69843//98370//473589

Comment: `There must not be any overlapping and no substrings of a longer substring` - so as I said, go down from the longest to x, not the other way around. No overlapping is fixed with always removing the current longest and putting a placeholder there (as per example in 3rd point). ;) Try implementing it. ;)